# How to declare global array of size defined in another file in C99?

Tags: c, arrays

Taking into account the VLA (variable length array) I would like to ask your opinions on the following problem: If an array is defined at global scope in one file:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};

// in the same file it is no problem to obtain the number of elements in arr by
#define arr_num sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
// or
enum {arr_num = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])};
```

The problem is that in other files in the same project I would like to create other arrays again at global scope with the same number of elements as there are in arr. But how can one achieve this in C99 if there is no way to 'extern' the enum or #define. Of course one can #define the number of elements of arr by hand in a header file and later use it in the other files but this is very inconvenient since by changing the number of elements in the array arr one has also to change by hand the value of this #define (this is even more inconvenient when arr is an array of structs).

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 2):

VLAs don't help with that: they need to be automatic variables, and hence you can't make a global variable a VLA. I agree with valdo that having a global variable containing the array size (or alternatively a function returning it) is the right approach.

Comment: From you suggestions I understood that the help of using a global const variable or a function depends on whether the compiler will do the optimization of replacing a variable or a return value with a integer constant or not and such compiler flags may not exist at all. Would you also please tell what kind of compiler flags one could use ? (I work with CodeSourcery compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A global `const` variable is just that, a *variable*. This is not C++. `const` variables are not valid in constant expressions.

Comment: The C language has the notion of a compile-time constant. A minimum requirement is that full expression is available at the point of use, including all subexpressions. Therefore, a const variable defined in a different translation unit cannot appear in a constant expression. This is not something that the compiler has a choice to do different.

Comment: Dear All, Thank you for all your opinions. Could you suggest any compiler which would support such a preprocessor flag which will optimize the C code in a way to deduct an integer constant from a const int g_arrCount = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); as suggested by valdo ? or from a function return value (as suggested by Martin Lowis) ? Or maybe I understood their opinion in a wrong way? Because otherwise as far as I understand there is no way to make a C compiler do the trick. Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want in C, no matter what compiler you use. So you need to achieve your more abstract objective with different means, such as the ones suggested by valdo (which is *not* exactly what you said you wanted, but what we think that you want after you accept it won't work exactly the way you want it).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do this according to C99. Because all the translation modules are compiled in an independent way, whereas `sizeof` should be known at compile time.

You may do something like this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
const int g_arrCount = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

// other translation unit
extern const int g_arrCount;
```

If you use a whole program optimization option - most likely the `g_arrCount` variable will be omitted completely, and instead its direct value will be used.

Comment: It's still invalid C even with whole-program optimization.